# Dynamically updated function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a for loop that goes though an array returned in JSON format. This gives me the ID & NAME of each image. I then have a variable that contains some HTML and some of the elements are dynamically updated by the responses. I then have a function to add/remove the image from the favourites sql db. But when i add the function into the onclick event of the anchor tag and use the id returned from the database it refuses to run (even though the function and the id are now visible in the html). ON with some code....

```
for (x in data.images) {            

    id = data.images[x].id,
    name = data.images[x].name,
    thumb = data.images[x].thumb    

output = '<div>\
              <a id="hil" href="viewer.php?id='+id+'">\
              <div>\
                   <img width="160px" height="160px" src="'+thumb+'">\
              </div>\
              </a>\

                  <div class="imft">
                      <a id="deladd" onclick="deladd('+id+')" class="deladd">
                          <img src="images/png/color_18/hand_thumbsup.png" />
                      </a> 
                  </div>\
                       <div>'+name+'</div>\
              </div>';

      $('#theImages').append(output); 
      $('#theImagesLoading').html('');
      $('#next').html('More');  

}
```

The function that doesn't run is deladd(), the id is passed into the function but the onclick event refuses to work. I can supply more code and/or information if needed.

Thanks for any help in advance.

JSON response for Michael Geary:

```
{"amount":4,"from":0,"limit":4,"images":{"1":     {"id":"3084f8d07be00e8af2ab4e7810b2e011","name":"Blossom.jpg","thumb":"thumbnails\/43efd305ac4381b2911d2cbaf212f9e0.jpg","ival":0},"2":{"id":"649d38a79f5980735be80156a83a27ff","name":"Wedding Sunflowe...","thumb":"thumbnails\/01dfca88ce1e699a6ab5d0e5c4adac5e.jpg","ival":1},"3":{"id":"ed2a2ff0c4e9ae319cdd791d8643f9e7","name":"Butterfly.JPG","thumb":"thumbnails\/6adcbf9bdf4b803654b291b2744c8a3b.jpg","ival":2},"4":{"id":"2f5e5540eceb27f9332deeb4cb44ae1c","name":"Creek.jpg","thumb":"thumbnails\/14eafef60824b9c755fc1737e6914ef1.jpg","ival":3}}}
```

Comment: How do you bind onClick event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few different problems in this code:

1. Never use a `for..in` loop to iterate through an array. Use a numeric `for` loop instead. (I'm assuming that `data.images` is an array using `[]`, not an object using `{}`, is that correct? It would be good to see an example of this JSON data.)
2. You need `var` declarations on all your local variables.
3. The HTML code it generates for the `deladd()` call is missing quotes around the ID. (I'm assuming that the ID is a string and not a number. If it's a number it would be OK as is.)
4. The HTML code is missing some `\` escapes, but I assume that's just a typo in the question.
5. The indentation isn't consistent.

This should fix those items:

```
for( var i = 0, n = data.images.length;  i < n;  i++ ) {

    var image = data.images[i],
        id = image.id,
        name = image.name,
        thumb = image.thumb;

    var output =
        '<div>\
            <a id="hil" href="viewer.php?id='+id+'">\
                <div>\
                    <img width="160px" height="160px" src="'+thumb+'">\
                </div>\
            </a>\
            <div class="imft">\
                <a id="deladd" onclick="deladd(\''+id+'\')" class="deladd">\
                    <img src="images/png/color_18/hand_thumbsup.png" />\
                </a>\
                </div>\
                <div>'+name+'</div>\
        </div>';

    $('#theImages').append(output); 
    $('#theImagesLoading').html('');
    $('#next').html('More');  
}
```

In addition, it might be better to use other methods for adding this event handler instead of the `onclick` attribute. But this should get you going for now.

Comment: Diamond! Forgot the quotes, what a wholly! Thanks for the help, and note taken regards to the loop. I'll use the numeric approach for loop iteration from now on.

Comment: The \, indentation and lack of var declaration are just typo's. Just added JSON response at bottom of the question for you.